# YouTube IFrame API and webkitExitFullScreen on IOS [revisit]

Tags: iphone, ios, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

How do I access the `webkitExitFullScreen` on mobile (iPhone) safari (`webkit`) functionality on full screen.

On an iPhone using the `IFrame API` a video always plays full screen, but I can't afterwards access different functionalities via JS like the `webkitExitFullScreen`.

I saw that this has been filed already to the forum and the team in the [YouTube API Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube-api-gdata) in here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/youtube-api-gdata/fygn23jMbdE/pNE57RDl1gEJ

and

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/7ioV74oFX84/U8zQ7-Yl9w4J

I wanted to ask and follow up on their questions especially the last one since it has been a year ago already. But the groups are now closed and said I should file here. Has anyone have any idea if this has been implemented somewhere in [the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) already and I might have been missing it? Or maybe how to contact the team and ask them directly about the progress or situation?

Comment: Likewise, I would like to know if there is an update here? @index did you get anywhere?

Comment: @addedlovely No. Not yet. This actually became a limitation for now for us. :( Anything on your side?

Comment: @addedlovely I've filed this on google's youtube API here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5710#makechanges and they mentioned that this is not in their plans anytime soon. :(

Comment: You can get a callback to iOS from a video exiting fullscreen however I think its seperate from JS callbacks so you wont be able to control the internals of the webview with it... but if you want to change your GUI or something it will help... Because the webkit uses the native MPMoviePlayer this notification will work perfectly. [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

Comment: Relevant discussion here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

write this in your viewdidload

```
 webView112 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
webView112.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
webView112.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webView112.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
webView112.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:webView112];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youtube" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[webView112 loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"any static url"]];
```

and the below method will fire after completion of your video

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
if ( [[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"callback"] )
{

    NSLog(@"get callback");
    [webView112 removeFromSuperview];

    return NO;
}

return YES;}
```

and create .html file and paste this code in .html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var elapsed = -1;
        var isPlayerLoaded = false;
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            player.playVideo();
        }

        //            function onPlayerError(event) {
        //            }
        //
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            var state = '';
            switch(event.data) {
                case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                   window.location = "callback:anything";
                    break;
                case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                    state = 'playing';
                    break;
                case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                    state = 'paused';
                    break;
                case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
                    state = 'buffering';
                    break;
                case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
                    state = 'cued';
                    break;
                default:
                    state = 'unstarted';
                    break;
            }
            jQuery('#log').append(state + "<br/>");
        }

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                                   height: '400',
                                   width: '320',
                                   videoId: 'y84oAUjA8ms',
                                   playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'iv_load_policy': 3, 'controls': 1, 'playsinline':1 },
                                   events: {
                                   'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                   'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                   //                                       'onError': onPlayerError
                                   }
                                   });
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body style="padding:0;margin:0;background-color:#000000;">
    <div id="log" style="background:#fff;height:0px;width:0%;margin-top:0px;"></div>
    <div id="player" frameborder="0"></div>
</body>
```